# The lower half of my pictures are black and the rest is normal?

Tags: repair, mirror-lens

I have a Canon Rebel T3 and everything was working fine when today I took it out to take some shots half of my pics and videos are black nothing is stuck the mirror mechanisam seems to work fine .. does anyone know what it could be? [image][image]

Answer (score 4):

You say nothing is stuck, but the sample images look almost certainly like you have a shutter curtain that is not fully opening. The amount of frame that is blocked seems to be variable as well.

Have you looked at the sensor with the camera in Live View mode and the lens removed? Can you see the entire sensor or is part of one of the shutter curtains blocking the top of the sensor? (The top of the sensor inside the camera is the bottom of the frame of photos and videos, since the lens inverts the image).

If there is nothing in front of the sensor when the mirror is up for Live View, then the problem is in the sensor itself or in the camera's LCD screen.

From comments by the OP:

> I wish I could send you a picture because I’m a beginner and I don’t understand how things should be aligned .. when I take off the lens and put it in Live mode one part goes up and a little part is down ... sorry about my description but I’m trying my best .. help ?!
>
> A little part from the main mirror is open and it’s a little mirror .. wow I really hope I’m explaining this well .

With your further description it sounds like the secondary mirror, which should fold up flat against the main mirror, is not flipping up properly. The camera will need to be repaired by a competent repair service or replaced.

Comment: I wish I could send you a picture becase I’m a begginer and I don’t understand how things should be alignied .. when I take off the lens and put it in Live mode one part goes up and a little part is down ... sorry about my describtion but I’m trying my best .. help ?!

Comment: Is the little part hanging from the bottom of the mirror? Or is it closer to the back of the camera and the sensor?

Comment: A little part from the main mirror is open and it’s a little mirror .. wow I really hope I’m explaining this well ..

Comment: Look at the animation in this video beginning at around 1:00. It shows how things should work. https://youtu.be/CmjeCchGRQo?t=1m

Comment: That's the secondary mirror. It should not be hanging down like that.

Comment: Well the secondary mirror stays open on Live view mode is there anyway I can fix this ?

Comment: The root cause is probably that something very small in the mirror assembly is broken. Replacing a mirror assembly is pretty delicate work and requires special tools to check proper alignment once it is done. Even adjusting a mirror is fairly advanced if nothing is actually broken.

Comment: I don’t see that anything is broken it just doesn’t follow the main mirror i push it up manually and it stays up but when taking a picture it doesn’t go up with the main mirror .. do you know if this is worth the fix I don’t want it to cost more than the camera itself .. and thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Whatever is supposed to push the secondary mirror against the main mirror as the main mirror swings up is what is broken. Canon's factory service pricing is based on tiers that include the extent of repair and the cost of the item being repaired plus parts cost. With such a low priced camera, though, just about any repair will be an appreciable percentage of what you paid for the camera. Contact Canon's customer service using the information in your camera's documentation and see if they'll give you an estimate.